# JS hasownproperty is not working, it returns false no matter what I do

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
console.log("findAllInvoice Result: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
console.log("hasOwnProperty Result: " + data.hasOwnProperty("totalInvoice"));
if (data.hasOwnProperty("totalInvoice")) {
    var myTotal = data.totalInvoice;
}
console.log("invoice Sum: " + myTotal)
console.log("=====RESOLVE findAllInvoice=====")
resolve(data);
```

Here is the result of the `console.log`:

```
=====RESOLVE findMonthBookings=====
findAllInvoice Result: [
    {
        "totalInvoice": 48758
    }
]
hasOwnProperty Result: false
invoice Sum: 0
=====RESOLVE findAllInvoice=====
```

I don't get it?! How can it return `false` when the property is clearly there?

Comment: As you can clearly see, `data` is an array with a `0` property

Comment: `data[0].hasOwn....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and change the second line to this:

```
console.log("hasOwnProperty Result: " + data[0].hasOwnProperty("totalInvoice"));
```

It needs to use `data[0]` instead of just `data`.

As you posted, `findAllInvoice` is an array with one element that is an object `[{"totalInvoice": 48758}]`. You need to call `hasOwnProperty` on that object instead of on the containing array.